# Binary Search Tree C

Tags: c, gdb, binary-tree

I have a problem with insertion in Binary search tree in C. I have the following definition of a binary tree(please ignore line numbers):

```
struct WordBT {
    char *term;
    struct WordBT *right;
    struct WordBT *left;
};

typedef struct WordBT* WordPtrBT;
WordPtrBT mainListBT;
```

And my insert function:

```
int addlistBT(char *term, char *file, WordPtrBT curr) {
    if (curr == NULL) {
        WordPtrBT temp =  (WordPtrBT)malloc(sizeof(WordPtrBT));
        temp->term = term;
        curr = temp;
        return 1;
    }

    int test = //some test;
    if (test == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (test > 0) {
        addlistBT(term, file, curr->left);
    }
    if (test < 0) {
        addlistBT(term, file, curr->right);
    }
}
```

Then i call

```
addlistBT(term, file, mainListBT);
```

I get a seg fault later on in the program. When i debug with gdb this is what i see:

```
                        curr = temp;
(gdb) p temp
$7 = (WordPtrBT) 0x60a2a0
(gdb) p curr
$8 = (WordPtrBT) 0x0
(gdb) p mainListBT
$9 = (WordPtrBT) 0x0
(gdb) n
93                      addfileBT(file, curr->file);
(gdb) p temp
$10 = (WordPtrBT) 0x60a2a0
(gdb) p curr
$11 = (WordPtrBT) 0x60a2a0
(gdb) p mainListBT
$12 = (WordPtrBT) 0x0
```

Now my question is that since mainListBT is defined as a pointer then why isnt mainListBT assigned the pointer to temp? 
Thanks

Comment: Its a darn shame KepaniHalo deleted his/her answer, because it was the right one. You're passing `mainListBT` by-value, not by-address, to `addlistBT()`. Consequently, nothing happens to the caller-side pointer variable, and your function leaks memory to add insult to injury

Comment: Beside @WhozCraig's comment, `malloc(sizeof(WordPtrBT))` is incorrect. It should be `malloc(sizeof(*temp))`

Comment: wait but mainListBT is defined as a pointer to the struct so am i not passing the pointer?

Comment: @SaadFarooq C is always pass-by-value, the only question is what value it is. Function is working with a copy of value, so changing it will have no results on calling side. If you passed pointer - you can dereference it and change value it points to (and have a change on calling side, because it's direct address), but not pointer itself - because in this context, pointer _is_ value you passing to function. If you pass pointer to pointer - you can change original data value and pointer to it, but not pointer to pointer you've passed. And so on. You can, however, `return` new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do:
call using addlistBT(term, file, &mainListBT);
Then change the addlist function to the following:

```
 81 int addlistBT(char *term, char *file, WordPtrBT *curr){
 86         if(!(*curr)){
 87                 WordPtrBT temp =  (WordPtrBT)malloc(sizeof(struct WordBT));
 88                 temp->term = term;
 92                 *curr = temp;
 94                 return 1;
 95         }
 96         int test = //some test;
 97         if(test == 0){  return 0;}
101         if(test > 0){   addlistBT(term, file, &(*curr)->left);}
104         if(test < 0){   addlistBT(term, file, &(*curr)->right);}
107 }
```

some pointer magic...

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple bugs in your program.

First, you are doing an equivalent of this:

```
void fn(int x) {
  x = 1;
}

int main() {
  x = 0;
  fn(x);
  // you expect x == 1 here, but you *should* expect 0.
}
```

Just as you need to pass `&x` instead of `x` into `foo()`, you need to pass `&mainListBT` into `addlistBT()` (and change its signature).

The second obvious bug is that this line:

```
WordPtrBT temp =  (WordPtrBT)malloc(sizeof(WordPtrBT));
```

allocates space for a *pointer*, when you want it to allocate space for the structure. It should be

```
WordPtrBT temp =  malloc(sizeof(*temp));
```

or

```
WordPtrBT temp =  malloc(sizeof(struct WordBT));
```

(and you should *never* cast result of `malloc` call).

Comment: Did you mean `sizeof(*temp)` in your first `malloc()` solution? (and +1)

Comment: ok the changes i did were: pass &mainListBT and change the signature. I also changed the malloc line to malloc(sizeof(*WordPtrBT)) and now the problem is that "error: request for member term in something not a structure or union". Same with malloc(sizeof(*temp))

Comment: @SaadFarooq Please see the update -- it answers your question.